# java gson deserialize policy

Tags: java, gson

I have a pojo which should be a json string representation

```
public class MyIncomingJsonLineItem implements Wrapper {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8902983775804518593L;

    @SerializedName("ProductName")
    private String productName=null;//           => 'Watch',

    @SerializedName("ProductDescription")
    private String productDescription=null;//    => 'Nice watch',

    @SerializedName("ProductSellingPrice")
    private BigDecimal productSellingPrice=null;//'   => 99.99,

    @SerializedName("ProductQty")
    private Integer productQty=null;//            => 2,

    @SerializedName("ProductCostPrice")
    private BigDecimal productCostPrice=null;//  
...
}
```

And I have a json string where ProductCostPrice ="" and ProductQty ="AA"

Then I want to get a filled object:

```
MyIncomingJsonLineItem ww=gson.fromJson(jsonString,MyIncomingJsonLineItem.class);
```

And I get many annoying exceptions that my string is not a number, and so on and so on. And I don't have any ability to know what  is exactly wrong, which field, etc. But this is a google lib, I can't believe I can't get comprehensive output of what's going on.

I create the gson like that:

```
GsonBuilder gb = new GsonBuilder();
gb.serializeNulls();
Gson gson = gb.create();
```

I also added a custom BigDecimal deserialize adapter, but should I create such adapters for all types, including built-in? I just tired hanging around this trivial function.

So the questions are:

1. How can I get a field name which's value is wrong?
2. How can I tell it to consider bad values as null?

**UPDATE**

Original exception:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$8.read(TypeAdapters.java:265) ~[gson-2.4.jar:na]
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$8.read(TypeAdapters.java:255) ~[gson-2.4.jar:na]
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:117) ~[gson-2.4.jar:na]
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:217) ~[gson-2.4.jar:na]
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:814) ~[gson-2.4.jar:na]
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:779) ~[gson-2.4.jar:na]
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:728) ~[gson-2.4.jar:na]
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:700) ~[gson-2.4.jar:na]
        at com.myapp.workers.core.WorkerHelper.convertFromPlainJsonPostString(WorkerHelper.java:348) ~[workers-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
        at com.myapp.workers.core.CommonListener.lambda$onMessage$1(CommonQueueListener.java:176) ~[workers-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
        at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextLong(JsonReader.java:977) ~[gson-2.4.jar:na]
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$8.read(TypeAdapters.java:263) ~[gson-2.4.jar:na]
        ... 12 common frames omitted
```

Comment: This seems like it would be easier to debug if we had (1) the contents of `jsonString` and (2) the actual exception(s) produced when you feed it to `fromJson`.

Comment: Thanks, I added my stacktrace, but can't provide a json string at the moment, please imagine that any numeric field has empty string in json string.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I realise that I misunderstood the point of the question -- which, I now see, was never "help me figure out why my deserialization is breaking" but "help me help my program figure out what's happening and recover from it".

Comment: Exactly, I need to catch the field with incorrect value and handle it. I don't think it's too difficult. I saw people create tons of awful adapters and classes to help gson, but I'm not a fan of such perversion. I need sth simple and reliable

Comment: You need to use an "awful" adapter. Thats what they are for.